# Why is Python Faster than LAPACK and C for SVD

Tags: python, c, performance, numpy, lapack

I recently had the need to compute an SVD from some C code. Given the stability and wide acceptance of LAPACK I decided to use that. The code seemed to be running a lot slower than I thought it should. I've been led to believe that Python and Numpy compute SVD via LAPACK, so I decided to compare speeds against Python. To my suprise the Python code is much faster at computing the SVD than the C code. In fact, the Python code can compute a full SVD about as fast as the C/LAPACK code computes half of an SVD.

This is my first real experience callling Fortran from C, so I suppose I am doing something wrong that is causing the slowdown, but I have no idea what it is.

> **Question:** Why is the Python code so much faster than the C code?

In the end I need a faster SVD in C, so the follow-on question is:

> **Question:** Is there a stable performant C library for computing partial SVD (preferrably of sparse matrices).

Here is some minimal code for timing tests. The matrix used doesn't have any particular meaning, i just needed something that I could easily generate in both C and Python.

**test_svd.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

extern void dgesvdx(
  char* jobu,
  char* jobv,
  char* range,
  int* m,
  int* n,
  double* a,
  int* lda,
  double* vl,
  double* vu,
  int* il,
  int* iu,
  int* ns,
  double* s,
  double* u,
  int* ldu,
  double* vt,
  int* ldvt,
  double* work,
  int* lwork,
  int* iwork,
  int* info);

extern void dgesdd(
  char* jobz,
  int* m,
  int* n,
  double* a,
  int* lda,
  double* s,
  double* u,
  int* ldu,
  double* vt,
  int* ldvt,
  double* work,
  int* lwork,
  int* iwork,
  int* info);

typedef enum bool {false, true} bool;

bool svd(double* a, 
         int num_rows,
         int num_cols,
         int num_sing_vals,
         double* u,
         double* s,
         double* vt,
         bool use_dgesdd) {
  double* a_work;
  int* iwork;
  double* work;
  int lwork;
  int min_m_n;
  int info = 0;
  double vl = 0;
  double vu = 1;
  int il = 1;
  int iu = num_sing_vals;
  int ns = num_sing_vals;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Compute and allocate optimal workspace
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  min_m_n = (num_cols < num_rows) ? num_cols : num_rows;
  lwork = -1;
  // copy a to prevent corruption
  a_work = (double*)malloc(num_cols*num_rows*sizeof(double));
  // compute optimal workspace (lwork)
  double worksize;
  if(use_dgesdd) {
    iwork = (int*)malloc(7*(min_m_n)*sizeof(int));
    dgesdd("S",&num_cols,&num_rows,a_work,&num_cols,s,vt,&num_cols,u,&num_sing_vals,&worksize,&lwork,iwork,&info);
  } else {
    iwork = (int*)malloc(24*(min_m_n)*sizeof(int));
    dgesvdx("V","V","I",&num_cols,&num_rows,a_work,&num_cols,&vl,&vu,&il,&iu,&ns,s,vt,&num_cols,u,&num_sing_vals,&worksize,&lwork,iwork,&info);
  }
  if(info) {
    perror("error computing lwork\n");
    return(false);
  }
  // allocate work
  lwork = (int)worksize;
  work = (double*)malloc(lwork*sizeof(double));

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Compute the svd
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  memcpy(a_work,a,num_cols*num_rows*sizeof(double));
  if(use_dgesdd) {
    dgesdd("S",&num_cols,&num_rows,a_work,&num_cols,s,vt,&num_cols,u,&num_sing_vals,work,&lwork,iwork,&info);
  } else {
    ns = num_sing_vals;
    dgesvdx("V","V","I",&num_cols,&num_rows,a_work,&num_cols,&vl,&vu,&il,&iu,&ns,s,vt,&num_cols,u,&num_sing_vals,work,&lwork,iwork,&info);
  }
  if(info<0) {
    perror("invalid argument in SVD\n");
    return(false);
  } else if(info>0) {
    printf("SVD did not converge");
    return(false);
  }
  free(iwork);
  iwork = NULL;
  free(work);
  work = NULL;
  free(a_work);
  a_work = NULL;
  return(true);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int num_rows = 1000;
  int num_cols = 1000;
  int size = num_rows*num_cols;
  double* A = (double*)calloc(num_rows*num_cols,sizeof(double));
  for(int r = 0; r < num_rows; ++r) {
    for(int c = 0; c < num_cols; ++c) {
      A[r*num_cols+c] = sin(5*M_PI*(r*num_cols+c)/((double)size))+cos(10*M_PI*(c*num_rows+c)/((double)size));
      if(fabs(A[r*num_cols+c])<0.75 || fabs(A[r*num_cols+c]) > 0.9) {
        A[r*num_cols+c] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  int num_sing_vals = (num_rows < num_cols) ? num_rows : num_cols;
  double* u_sdd = (double*)calloc(num_rows*num_sing_vals,sizeof(double));
  double* s_sdd = (double*)calloc(num_sing_vals,sizeof(double));
  double* vt_sdd = (double*)calloc(num_sing_vals*num_cols,sizeof(double));
  clock_t tic = clock();
  bool success = svd(A,num_rows,num_cols,num_sing_vals,u_sdd,s_sdd,vt_sdd,true);
  clock_t toc = clock();
  printf("full dgesdd %lf seconds\n",(double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  double* u_svd = (double*)calloc(num_rows*num_sing_vals,sizeof(double));
  double* s_svd = (double*)calloc(num_sing_vals,sizeof(double));
  double* vt_svd = (double*)calloc(num_sing_vals*num_cols,sizeof(double));
  tic = clock();
  success = svd(A,num_rows,num_cols,num_sing_vals,u_svd,s_svd,vt_svd,false);
  toc = clock();
  printf("full dgesvdx %lf seconds\n",(double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  int first_few_sv = 200;
  double* u_partial_svd = (double*)calloc(num_rows*first_few_sv,sizeof(double));
  double* s_partial_svd = (double*)calloc(num_sing_vals,sizeof(double));
  double* vt_partial_svd = (double*)calloc(first_few_sv*num_cols,sizeof(double));
  tic = clock();
  success = svd(A,num_rows,num_cols,first_few_sv,u_partial_svd,s_partial_svd,vt_partial_svd,false);
  toc= clock();
  printf("partial dgesvdx %lf seconds\n",(double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  free(A);
  free(u_sdd);
  free(s_sdd);
  free(vt_sdd);
  free(u_svd);
  free(s_svd);
  free(vt_svd);
  free(u_partial_svd);
  free(s_partial_svd);
  free(vt_partial_svd);
  return 0;
}
```

compiling with:

```
gcc test_svd.c -O3 -lm -llapack -Ddgesdd=dgesdd_ -Ddgesvdx=dgesvdx_
```

This gives me the following timing outputs:

```
full dgesdd 8.003578 seconds
full dgesvdx 17.077815 seconds
partial dgesvdx 1.498775 seconds
```

Comparing with the following python code:

**test_svd.py**

```
import numpy, time
dim = 1000
term1 = numpy.sin((5*numpy.pi*numpy.arange(dim**2).reshape(dim,dim))/(dim**2))
term2 = numpy.cos((10*numpy.pi*numpy.arange(dim**2).reshape(dim,dim).T)/(dim**2))
A = term1+term2
A = numpy.where(numpy.abs(A)<0.75,0,A)
A = numpy.where(numpy.abs(A)>0.9,0,A)
tic = time.time()
U,S,Vt = numpy.linalg.svd(A)
toc = time.time()
print "full svd", toc - tic, "seconds"
```

gives:

```
python2 test_svd.py
full svd 2.4460 seconds
```

The actual singluar values agree. However, the fact that a full SVD in Python is comparable in time to a partial SVD in C is puzzling to me.

In case it matters my python is Python 2.7.12 compiled with GCC 6.2.1 and my gcc is 6.2.1

Comment: That function is most probably implemented in fortran inside numpy

Comment: What @BlackBear said is right - `numpy`'s `svd` implementation is actually in optimized [C/Fortran](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L2784). Many of the core Numpy math functions are written in C and contained in [`npymath`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html), a C library that was designed to enable cross-library integration (SciPy uses it, for example).

Comment: I see a much smaller difference between LAPACK and numpy here.  1.42s (LAPACK dgesdd) *vs*. 1.17s (numpy).  Are you perhaps using a LAPACK build that is not tuned for your architecture?  I do find it a bit surprising that numpy wins, but it does have the advantage of being written for a much narrower variety of input forms.  As other comments have observed, this is not Python beating C / Fortran, it is one C / Fortran implementation beating a different one.

Comment: Check which LAPACK you link to in your C program and when using numpy. Reference implementations are expected to be orders of magnitude slower than fine-tuned ones.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There are different algorithms available to compute the svd. According to the [docs of LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/db4/dgesdd_8f_source.html), `DGESDD` uses a divide and conquer method (DBDSDC). `DGESVDX` uses an eigenvalue problem (DBDSVDX), `DGESVD` uses a QR decomposition, `DGESVJ` may be able to handle tiny singular values... Looking at [the sources of numpy.linalg](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py), it is likely that numpy falls back to LAPACK's `DGESDD`.

Comment: Notice also that calling `malloc()` allocate memory, but it does not perform any copy... Hence, the array `awork` is not initialized in your svd... Could you try to add a call to [`memcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) there?

Comment: @francis there is a memcpy before the second call to the Fortan code. The first call shouldn't reference a_work, it is just determining array sizes.

Comment: @John I installed it via ATLAS with the cpu throttling disabled so it should be tuned to my architecture, but maybe something went wrong. This seems to be the only sensible thing thus far since if both C and numpy are using dgesdd, then the python overhead should result in some (even if small) slowdown compared to the C.